# AWS Media Convert - Generating sprite for video preview on progress bar hovering

Tags: amazon-s3, sprite, aws-media-convert

Here is my process :

1. I upload a video in an S3 bucket
2. I encode the video with AWS media converter
3. The videos are generated by AWS Media converter
4. I need "something" to create a sprite like the picture below so I can use it to display the video on hover

[image]

If anyone has a solution or just an idea, I'll be very interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could code a solution that shouldn't be too hard. I'm not sure exactly what your architecture is, but you [could bootstrap an EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html) instance with an install of [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org), and script out your thumbnail reel with [something like this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video). [Imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) is another solution, see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/599348/can-imagemagick-make-thumbnails-from-video).

You could probably even run that solution in Lambda. [Here's a generic image processing post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/cutting-costs-with-aws-lambda-for-highly-scalable-image-processing/) using that technology.

In either case, once up, you can [configure s3 to fire an event when a video is dropped](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-configure-s3-event-notification/) and [use Lambda natively](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) or something like [SQS or SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) to notify your ec2 instance to extract and store the thumbnail reel alongside the video file in S3 using a solution similar to this [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-cost-effective-queue-workers-with-amazon-sqs-and-amazon-ec2-spot-instances/).

Again, this assumes a lot about your architecture, but hopefully there are some useful pointers in there. Feel free to leave comments if you have questions. Happy to help.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just to clarify (I've edited the question), the thumbnails are generated by media transcoder. So all I need is that "something" to build the sprite from the jpg files. I'll look into your pointers. Thank you

Comment: The term you're looking for is "contact sheet", I think. [Here's a repo](https://github.com/amietn/vcsi) that does it. And [here is a post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63769/fast-tool-to-generate-thumbnail-video-galleries-for-command-line) that seems to do exactly what you're looking for, including the "something". Best of luck!